# The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, asmx

I am trying to convert some vb.net to C#, but I keep getting errors.  At the moment, I am getting the error in the title.

The problem line is:

```
string[] strUserInitials = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").Split(Convert.ToChar("\\"));
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

I am working on a webservice (asmx file).

I have the following at the top of the code:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: As it's a WebService, you could try using `OperationContext` instead?

Comment: I'm now getting `The name 'OperationContext' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: I think it's the [] brackets as @alun posted below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `[]` instead of `()` :

```
string[] strUserInitials = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Split(System.Convert.ToChar(@"\"));
```

Comment: Now getting `The name 'Convert' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Convert is in the system namespace so either change it to System.Convert or add using System;

Comment: @shirowanen: Why do you use Convert? Use '\\'.

Comment: add `System.Web.dll` reference, check how to do that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/422895/The-name-HttpContext-does-not-exist-in-the-current), hope helps some one.

Answer (score 21):

You have to reference to System.Web and import the namespace System.Web:

```
using System.Web;
```

I would not use Convert at all:

```
string[] strUserInitials = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Split('\\'));
```

Answer (score 3):

put `using System.Web;` and `using System;` into the source file...